# CosmosDBTrigger: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

When I try to execute newly created azure function with CosmosDBTrigger, I get the above exception for the function with cosmosdb trigger

Investigative information

**Environment:**
Visual Studio 2017 15.3.5

Packages referenced:

- Marvin.JsonPatch.Dynamic Version="1.1.0"
- Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB Version="1.17.0"
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs Version="2.1.0-beta4"
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB Version="1.1.0-beta4"
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus Version="2.0.0"
- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions Version="1.0.5"
- Newtonsoft.Json Version="10.0.3"
- System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager Version="4.4.0"

**Steps to reproduce the issue**

Provide the steps required to reproduce the problem:

- Create a new Azure Function Project from Visual Studio
- Add a function (i didn't find any option for CosmosDB Binding so i created using HttpTrigger)
  once the .cs file is created, replace the file with the code that i have put below.
- Build
- Hit F5

Here is the code sample

```
    public static class AddEventInEventStore
    {
        [FunctionName("AddEventInEventStore")]
        public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger("db", "Items",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureWebJobsDocumentDBConnectionString",
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases", LeaseDatabaseName = "db"
            )]
            IReadOnlyList<Document> changeList, TraceWriter log)
        {
            if (changeList != null && changeList.Count > 0)
            {
                log.Verbose("Documents modified " + changeList.Count);
                foreach (var change in changeList)
                {
                    log.Verbose("First document Id " + change.Id);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: So which line throws the exception?

Comment: Hi Mikhail, it's not the code itself, i don't even reach there. the error is thrown in the host console ( i have attached the picture in my post above).

Comment: Do you get the same error in clean project without those extra packages referenced? (I just tried, works for me)

Comment: So you removed all other referenced packages?

Comment: No, I have a clean project with `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` and `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB`

Comment: Can you please tell me what version have you for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB package?

Comment: Same as yours, 1.1.0-beta4. Do other types of triggers work for you? Do you have `AzureWebJobsStorage` setting configured in `local.settings.json`?

Comment: I still get the same, these are the only two nuget packages i have in my clean project now: <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB" Version="1.1.0-beta4" />    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.5" />

Comment: Try updating Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools? (Tools -> Extensions)

Comment: It did indeed did the trick !! Thanks a ton! i did update all other tools but somehow didn't think about this. Now i have other challenges with some other packages as it seems but atleast this issue is out of my way :) Thanks for the help mikhail !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools (Tools -> Extensions and Updates).

I can see you are on `1.0.0` version (console title), while `1.0.4` is already available.